# Need to change formatting of font color within wordpress blog post

Tags: html, wordpress, formatting, format, blogs

On my page currently the blog posts all have white text, which is what I want. When I click into a post from the main site to the specific blog post, the title color and link color change(See links). My site is live and need help figuring out if this can be fixed..

How do I fix this so that they remain white like they are on the main blog roll page…

**Example:**

Main: www.trinitybeats.com

Specific posting: http://www.trinitybeats.com/archie-horizon-original-mix/ (Notice the title color and link color)

**Here is the code specific for the blog formatting:**

```
 <div class="hentry-inner">

<div class="entry-wrapper grids">

    <?php get_template_part('content', 'meta'); ?>

    <div class="entry-content grid-10 clearfix">

        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'stag'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <?php

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }

        the_content(__('Continue Reading', 'stag'));

        wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'stag').'</strong> ',   'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number'));

        $embed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stag_audio_embed', true);

        if(!empty($embed)){
            echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($embed));
        }else{
            stag_audio_player(get_the_ID());
        }

        ?>

    </div>
    <span class="bottom-accent"></span>
</div>
```

**Is there anything within this code that I can fix to keep the font color white when going into a specific blog page?**

Thank you!

Comment: Somewhere you within the Wordpress setup you should find some CSS files with the ending .css.

Then, read up on hover and link state styling http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem hs nothing to do with wordpress, its rather a css issue ..

You can add following code snippet in your theme's style.css hope this would work for you ..

```
.entry-title a {
    color:#ffffff!important;
}

.entry-title a:active {
    color:#ffffff!important;
}
.entry-title a:focus {
    color:#ffffff!important;
}
```

for the link part  on line no 129 replace this piece of your code :

```
.single-format-audio .entry-content a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

}
```

with this

```
.single-format-audio .entry-content a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        color:white!important;

    }
```

Comment: for link look for proper css selector and do something similar .

Comment: can you give me the specific code like you did for title? Thank you

Comment: surely i can give, but i dont know which link you are talking about post a screenshot maybe ?

Comment: the link within the specific blog post page is still a color rather than white: 

http://www.trinitybeats.com/cris-cab-liar-liar-feat-pharrell-williams/

Comment: and on the regular site it is white: trinitybeats.com 

same as the issue as I was mentioning above, you fixed it with the title just not the link towards the bottom of the page

Comment: ok simply paste that piece of code in your style.css in last ?

Comment: nevermind! added it in!! My theme has a custom ccs box to add in custom code! that fixed it! Thank you for all your help!